# Upgrade disc-brake wheels

Tags: wheels, disc-brake

Just bought new bike with disc brakes.  If I buy an upgrade wheelset do brake discs (rotors) come with?  Or do you have to buy them separately?

Comment: Given you've just bought the bike, leave upgrades alone for a while.  Get some mileage on the bike before you spend more money on it.

Comment: Just transfer your old rotors to the new wheel. All you'll need is an allen key and some thread lock.

Answer (score 10):

Normally the rotors will be separate. Also, there are two kinds of rotor mounts: 6-bolt and centerlock. You can get an adapter to put a 6-bolt rotor on a centerlock hub (I don't think you can go the other way), so it's something to be aware of.